# How to add external fonts to android application

Tags: android, android-fonts

I was looking for some stylish fonts for my android application. but the problem is how can i make my android application supportable for external fonts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You need to create fonts folder under assets folder in your project and put your TTF into it. Then in your Activity onCreate()

```
TextView myTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textBox);
Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/mytruetypefont.ttf");
myTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

Please note that not all TTF will work. While I was experimenting, it worked just for a subset (on Windows the ones whose name is written in small caps).

Comment: where is this assets folder? I am using android studio and I can find it in under src/

Comment: It is not under src, assets folder should be under your main project folder (at the same level as: src, res, gen, bin...) Check: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Comment: @Zelimir isn't there a way to dis universally for the project? and not take each TextView and set it's typeface?

Comment: @libathos - sounds reasonable, but I am not sure how to do that. Did not have time to investigate, have you?

Comment: @libathos well you can define a Typeface through xml but that actually  requires more writing than having it in coding

Comment: This way not. See questions above.

Comment: You can sub class the font in you project and use that font in your xml

Comment: Can a user import a font into the app at runtime or must all fonts live within the assets folder when the apk is built?

Answer (score 12):

You can use the custom TextView for whole app with custom font here is an example for that

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

   Typeface normalTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), Constants.FONT_REGULAR);
   Typeface boldTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),  Constants.FONT_BOLD);

   public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   }

   public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   }

   public MyTextView(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }

   public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
       if (style == Typeface.BOLD) {
           super.setTypeface(boldTypeface/*, -1*/);
       } else {
           super.setTypeface(normalTypeface/*, -1*/);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Create a folder named fonts in the assets folder and add the snippet from the below link.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"fonts/fontname.ttf");
textview.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 7):

To implement you need use Typeface go through with sample below

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
for (View view : allViews)
{
   if (view instanceof TextView) 
   {
      TextView textView = (TextView) view;
      textView.setTypeface(typeface);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: for `allViews` you have to loop through the layout using `getChildCount()`
so you could just replace the foreach with a simple for loop.

Answer (score 5):

> The easiest way to accomplish this is to package the desired font(s)
>   with your application. To do this, simply create an assets/ folder in
>   the project root, and put your fonts (in TrueType, or TTF, form) in
>   the assets. You might, for example, create assets/fonts/ and put your
>   TTF files in there.
>
> Then, you need to tell your widgets to use that font. Unfortunately,
>   you can no longer use layout XML for this, since the XML does not know
>   about any fonts you may have tucked away as an application asset.
>   Instead, you need to make the change in Java code, by calling
>   Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), “fonts/HandmadeTypewriter.ttf”),
>   then taking the created Typeface object and passing it to your
>   TextView via setTypeface().

For more reference here is the tutorial where I got this:

http://www.androidguys.com/2008/08/18/fun-with-fonts/

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this [approach](https://gist.github.com/twaddington/3739637) it very nice with adding name of custom font in `typeface` to `styles.xml` and putting your set of fonts into `assets` folder.

Comment: Very good approach, I suggest to take it to an attention. And maybe is a good idea to copy main code and post here, if link won't be accessible in the future.

Answer (score 2):

**One more point** in addition to the above answers.
When using a font inside a fragment, the typeface instantiation should be done in the onAttach method ( override ) as given below:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"fonts/fontname.ttf");
}
```

**Reason**: 
There is a short span of time before a fragment is attached to an activity. If CreateFromAsset method is called before attaching fragment to an activity an error occurs.