# how to add font in Android Application

Tags: android, textview, android-fonts

i am making one application in Android 2.2 in that application 
i want to show hindi text in TextView  in Android application. (how to add "मैं छात्र हूँ" word in Text view)

Please help me..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add external fonts to android application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634245/how-to-add-external-fonts-to-android-application)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add your font to assets folder in your project and use the below snippet

```
 TextView hindiTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtbx);
 Typeface hindiFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/fontname.ttf");
 mytextView.setTypeface(hindiFont);
```

Hope its helpful.

Comment: Its not working,showing only rectangle boxes, i have included vigyapti.ttf file

Comment: showing error on font folder..where to include font folder..I included inside resource folder

Comment: you have to include it to the assets folder, as @Jana says.

Comment: what if I want to use the font in entire app? is there any way to mention font in  manifest?

Answer (score 3):

1) add "fonts" folder inside of "assets" folder and paste font inside of fonts folder

2) in layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
             android:orientation="vertical"  
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        >  

    <TextView  
           android:id="@+id/custom_font"  
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
           android:text="मैं छात्र हूँ"  
           />
```

3) In Activity where you want to set the text use the code below:

```
 TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);  
 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "hindifont.ttf");  
 txt.setTypeface(font);
```