# How to add a font that can be used throughout the application?

Tags: android, android-fonts

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6463529/1433826), I know you can add fonts in an activity and can use it within that class. Using:

```
 TextView hindiTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtbx);
 Typeface hindiFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/fontname.ttf");
 mytextView.setTypeface(hindiFont);
```

But what if I want to add a font in a single place and use it in the entire applicaiton? (Like in manifest or some property file)

Comment: No by default android does not have such way for custom fonts. You can write a utility class and put the code related to get custom typeface from there.

Comment: And if you are planning to use custom fonts and you can design your custom components then http://vision-apps.blogspot.in/2012/02/android-better-way-to-apply-custom-font.html should be best start.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is not way to implement common custom font for whole application.
 Checkout [HERE](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/08/18/fun-with-fonts/) **Which is to say: no, you can't set a font for the entire application.**

But still if you want to try out ,try as below which is referenced [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application):

Common fonts class:

```
public final class FontsOverride {

    public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
            String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
        final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                fontAssetName);
        replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
    }

    protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
            final Typeface newTypeface) {
        try {
            final Field StaticField = Typeface.class
                    .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
            StaticField.setAccessible(true);
            StaticField.set(null, newTypeface);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You then need to overload the few default fonts, for example:

```
FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", "MyFontAsset.ttf");
FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", "MyFontAsset2.ttf");
FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SANS_SERIF", "MyFontAsset3.ttf");
```

Or course if you are using the same font file, you can improve on this to load it just once.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. You can only add custom fonts using the code you've just written.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class which extends TextView , add the font logic their . Instead of using android TextView in layout , use  `<com.mypackage.myTextView android:id="@+id/myid  />`