# kannada text support on older Android devices

Tags: android, kannada

how to show kannada text on older devices.
I have tried with font files but rendering is not correct.
I have tried indic text renderer but I was stuck at

```
SharedLibrary  : libcomplex-script-rendering.so
C:/users/vamsikrishna.g/Downloads/indic-text-renderer-72ba1d4f4f36/obj/local/armeabi/objs/complex-script-rendering/complex-script-rendering.o: In function `Java_org_iisc_mile_indictext_android_EditIndicText_drawIndicText':
C:/users/vamsikrishna.g/Downloads/indic-text-renderer-72ba1d4f4f36/jni/complex-script-rendering.c:136: undefined reference to `hb_ft_font_create'
```

I was not able to resolve this issue which is experienced by lot of people .

so if any body resolved or has any ideas on rendering kannada text on old Android phones
please help.

Comment: Try to set the kannada font in your text view.

Comment: thats i already did but rendering is not correct

Answer (score 0):

*Now, far sure it is clear that a TTF file should be present to provide characters and an appropriate libraries (libskia.so or libharfbuzz.so i.e. as an example ) are required to render them correctly.
Replace the firmware of your device with similar Indian region's firmware to render the Kannada font correctly. Other regions' firmware do not render the Kannada fonts correctly. Kannada fonts correctly render on Indian Region's Android version 2.x.*

please raise the points if you found this solution feasible,will be thankful to you.

Comment: i want to make an application in kannada that supports all devices from 2.2 so replacing firmware is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a particular application:

You need to keep the ttf file in your assests folder and

follow the link...

[how to add font in Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463397/how-to-add-font-in-android-application)

this one in for hindi... You can do the same for kannada