# How to load Myanmar font in android webview?

Tags: android, css, android-webview, font-face, southeast-asian-languages

I have set my custom font in css:

```
@font-face 
{
   font-family: 'myanmar';
   src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/ZawgyiOne.ttf'); 
}
.mm
{
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'myanmar';
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style:normal;
    color: red;
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<span class='mm'>This sentence contain:  ျမန္မာ ၾကိဳဆိုပါ၏</span>
```

I only see "This sentence contain:" and nothing appears in the place of myanmar font. Is there something else that I need to add on?

Comment: What platform version are you using? Does it work with other custom fonts and just not this one?

Comment: yes. It works with other font. I'm using android 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to [add the font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634245/how-to-add-external-fonts-to-android-application) to the resources.  I'm still not sure that will translate to the webview though.

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.3 didn't work with myanmar unicode. For zawgyi , you should try with SVG font for android webview. Other myanmar unicode can't work in android 4.3