# Android assets retrieve embedded font for Typeface

Tags: android, file, assets, typeface

I've managed to embed a font which I can access through Typeface.createFromAsset, however, there is also the "file:///android_asset/.." protocol.

I tried using "file:///android_asset/fonts/myfont.ttf" for Typeface.createFromFile, but this does not work ? Strange as I would have thought that file:///android_asset is handled by the system and thus Typeface would be able to get an InputStream ?

So my specific question is: Why doesn't the file:///android_asset/ protocol work with Typeface.createFromFile ?

Comment: Have you tried as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634245/how-to-add-external-fonts-to-android-application

Comment: Yes, that is what I wrote first "I've managed to embed..." ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I opted for was to write a binary array into a cache file, then use `Typeface.createFromFile(path)` with the cache file.

The solution looks like this:

```
final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

public static String bytesToHex (byte[] bytes)
{
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];

    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; ++j)
    {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xff;
        hexChars[j * 2]     = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0f];
    }

    return new String (hexChars);
}

final private java.util.Map dataCache = new java.util.HashMap();

synchronized private final File getDataCacheFile (byte[] data)
{
    try
    {
        java.security.MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance ("MD5");
        digest.update (data);

        String key = bytesToHex (digest.digest());

        if (dataCache.containsKey (key))
            return (File) dataCache.get (key);

        File f = new File (this.getCacheDir(), "bindata_" + key);
        f.delete();
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream (f);
        os.write (data, 0, data.length);
        dataCache.put (key, f);
        return f;
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {}

    return null;
}

private final void clearDataCache()
{
    java.util.Iterator it = dataCache.values().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        File f = (File) it.next();
        f.delete();
    }
}

public final Typeface getTypeFaceFromByteArray (byte[] data)
{
    try
    {
        File f = getDataCacheFile (data);

        if (f != null)
            return Typeface.createFromFile (f);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e ("<tag>", e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Did you actually get this to work, and on which version of Android? AFAIK, this method can only be used for loading fonts from `system/fonts/`, and won't work for any non-system font.

Comment: getTypeFaceFromByteArray can be called with a font as binary data, works nicely :) on 4.4.2 anyways. See edited answer.

Comment: Basically, your solution implies that `Typeface.createFromFile()` works with files from cache dir, but at least on my device (Android 6.0) it doesn't. And according to this: http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/tools/layoutlib/bridge/src/android/graphics/FontFamily_Delegate.java (look for addFont() method) - it shouldn't work. Not sure about 4.4.2 though...

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I haven't tested this in a while, so it might indeed be broken.

Answer (score 1):

To `Typeface.createFromFile(path)` method you have to pass the path which is related to the device you are running the app. So this method will look for the font file in the device directory but not in the asset folder. If you give the path like `file:///android_asset/ protocol` then it will not found the device file system. So it will not works.

Comment: Ok. Still, you can create a File as File(URI uri), so I would still suspect that I can use this for my own URLSchemeHandler implementation ? My end goal is to be able to create a Typeface from a binary resource.

Comment: What you mean by binary resource??

Comment: I have a TrueType font which I load into a a byte array, i.e. byte[], and want to create the Typeface from that byte array, so idea is to create a special URI protocol and a URLSchemeHandler for that so I can return an InputStream referring to that byte array.