# Android Studio, Design view font change

Tags: android, fonts

I changed the font in my application to a custom font, but I don't know how to change the font in Android Studio in the design view, where you can drag n drop buttons, textviews, etc.... Any ideas? Because of this I can't position correctly the buttons on my layout, because it's different in emulator, and different in design view. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't set custom font at design view. you set custom font using only java code.**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the custom font in android you have to add that font in assets and use it from there. Use these links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634245/how-to-add-external-fonts-to-android-application) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font) hope this can help

Comment: I added the fonts to my app, it's not the problem. The problem is that I want to see the custom font in the layout design editor too, you know, when you do click on the "Design" tab, this is where I'm not see the custom font, only the default, and I don't know how to change it.