# android - install font to android platform without root

Tags: android, fonts, android-fonts

I develop new app that wrote (coptic) its an old Egyptian language , I need to install specific font to android platform make this language readable .

I search if find app do the same function **iFont**

plus when I access font folder, I find its allowable to install font

Get fonts online , so how can I install font programatically to this folder

thank you

[image]

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634245/how-to-add-external-fonts-to-android-application ?

Comment: yea I don't make bounty to ask about typeface , I mean install font to android platform

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to install new fonts without root, the [iFont](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kapp.ifont) app only works without root on very few devices (please check their app description).

If you developed an app that needs a specific font, you should use the [Typeface solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634245/how-to-add-external-fonts-to-android-application).

Comment: so can we do something else , like broadcast track all e-mail to open with this font

Comment: @minafawzy It isn't possible to install new fonts on a system level without root access on most devices (with the exception of a few Samsung phones) like @thiagolr answered. The reason is because the fonts reside in the `system/fonts` directory, which isn't accessible to an app on a non-rooted device. However, you could try the Typeface solution as @thiagolr suggested.

Comment: typeface be readable in my app only , in this this font be readable throw whole device

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to ship the font in your app by yourself and work with `Typeface`, as mentioned by **@thiagolr**. The easiest solution is to use [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) in your project, so you can apply a custom font in your whole project in an easy way.