# android - setup and install Custom Font in Android without root

Tags: java, android

I developed an Android application which is a custom keyboard with a custom font.
I developed the keyboard successfully but I'm stuck for changing the font. How can I install and setup a custom font in my Android device ?
I need to setup the font with my keyboard in the same application.

I used the *iFont* application to install the font on the device without root access. 
I searched if I could find code do the same function than the *iFont* application.
How can I install a font programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

there is no way.it is possible only on Rooted devices and some special devices (like "Samsung").
[android - install font to android platform without root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996621/android-install-font-to-android-platform-without-root)

Comment: I used the IFont application without root . how can Ifont do the code if it is not possible .
even how i fond emoji or custom keyboard used the custom font ?

Comment: as i said , its works on some special devices , too.like "samsung" android devices.and not on all devices.

Comment: is it possible to install font programatically on rotted devices ?

Comment: Yes.see this folder on your rooted android device: "/system/fonts"