# What are the different ways to Change font Style in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new in android app development. I want to change fonts of my Application.
Just i wanna know different methods for change the font by XML and Java to.
 Want to change the font of :
1.TextView
2.RadioButton
3.EditText
4.CheckBox etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In Android Studio Right click on **app** & create a folder **assets**.
2. Right click on **assets** and create a folder **fonts**.
3. Download .ttf file i.e fontName.ttf and paste inside fonts folder.

Now you have to do main things. Inside your package create a class.

**This class is for TextView**

```
public class Railway_Regular extends TextView {
public Railway_Regular(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf"));
}}
```

**This class is for Button**

```
public class Railway_Regular_Btn extends Button {
public Railway_Regular_Btn(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf"));
}}
```

**This class is for EditText**

```
public class Railway_Regular_EdTx extends EditText {
public Railway_Regular_EdTx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf"));
}}
```

Like these you can create classes for all you Widgets & reference the fontname.ttf to your classes.

Now,for set textview as your font do this.

**for TextView**

```
<package_name.fonts.Railway_Regular
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:id="@+id/test_nameDR"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Details Text"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

**for Button**

```
 <package_name.fonts.Railway_Regular_Btn
    android:id="@+id/revSubmit"
    android:background="@color/greenDeep"
    android:layout_marginTop="-54dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:text="SUBMIT REVIEW"
    />
```

**for EditText**

```
   <package_name.fonts.Railway_Regular_EdTx
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/lightgray"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                android:id="@+id/email_id"
                android:hint="Email Id"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

**Second Method to Change your font :**

```
  Typeface typeface,typeface2;
  typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf");
  typeface2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/Raleway-SemiBold.ttf");

 button1.setTypeface(typeface);
 edit_text1.setTypeface(typeface2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TTF format to change the font

```
 tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
      tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

      Typeface face= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/font.ttf");
      tv1.setTypeface(face);

      Typeface face1= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/font1.ttf");
      tv2.setTypeface(face1);
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm

http://tekeye.uk/android/examples/android-textview-edittext-font

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically using the below code for RadioButton/TextView/Checkbox -

Also make sure that you have the corresponding .ttf file inside your Assets folder.

```
RadioButton rb  = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "SF_Cartoonist_Hand_Bold.ttf");
rb.setTypeface(font);
```

Or you can do it inside your xml file inside your TextView by entering this -

From android 4.1 / 4.2 / 5.0, the following Roboto font families are available:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"     // roboto black
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"      // roboto thin (android 4.2)
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"    // roboto medium (android 5.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change font of your application so create fonts folder under assets folder in your project and put your TTF into it.May be It will help you [How to add external fonts to android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634245/how-to-add-external-fonts-to-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can use various methods to change your font. One of them is:

```
  Typeface typeface,typeface2;
  typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/Raleway-
  Regular.ttf");
  typeface2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/Raleway-
  SemiBold.ttf");

  button1.setTypeface(typeface);
  edit_text1.setTypeface(typeface2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `themes.xml`, I put this line into the theme, which was assigned to the app in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">EnterFontFamilyNameHere</item>
```